# Access theta from random effect model in plm()

Tags: r, plm

I am running a random effects model and would like to take the theta object (the quasi-demeaned variance) and store it to an object. Looking around, it is not clear what this is stored as in a `plm()` object or where it comes from when I run the `summary()` function.

Here’s an example of code:

```r
library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")
zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, 
    data = Produc, index = c("state", "year"),
    model = "random")

summary(zz)
```

```
...
Effects:
                   var  std.dev share
idiosyncratic 0.001454 0.038137 0.175
individual    0.006838 0.082691 0.825
theta: 0.8888
...
```

I thought I might access it by doing `theta <- zz$theta` but that returns NULL.

Anyone more familiar with how this package works who could give advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: When in doubt, use `str(zz)` to see what lives inside the object ...

Comment: I didn’t know about str() that’s helpful! I had kept seeing a lot of recs to use broom but it wasn’t exactly what I wanted. But str() is definitely a new handy trick thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ercomp` element of the model object contains the estimation of various component errors. You perhaps mean to get theta from `zz$ercomp$theta`; however, you do not have a random effects model in your original post?

Comment: I just modified OP's model to use `model = "random"` ...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There is no `ercomp` component unless a random effects model has been requested; that is why you probably did not see (I just read your comment above)

Comment: Yes! Sorry the code in the original question was not a random effect. That was an error. My apologies. Thank you for correcting that and for the answer.